# Did Stack Overflow trust "Screenleap"?

Tags: discussion, advertising

I was looking for an API to share my screen to a browser, and saw this:
[image]
`https://www.screenleap.com/pricing`

Did you actually "trust" their product in some way or are they abusing the logo?

Comment: While on it, if someone knows a tool which can be installed on a PC / Mac and it can stream the screen to a browser, I'll be glad to hear about it `:)`

Comment: I assume that by "trusted" they mean those companies use the product in some capacity.

Comment: @Servy, I know, but I want to make sure that is true. If SO is actually using it, I know it's safe for me too and I don't need to investigate it myself.

Comment: People here don't have a soul, a guy makes a tremendous effort with almost a perfect freehand circle, and people downvote. **YOU ALL ARE GOING TO HELL!**

Comment: Honestly, I would investigate it before using it _even if_ Stack Overflow uses it. Even if it's completely legit and cool, it still might not be quite right for you while being exactly what Stack Overflow needs.

Comment: I luckily got to screenshare for a beta docs feature, and google hangouts was used.

Comment: This is such a sneaky way to get away with asking a software recommendation question on SO. +1. And another +1 for the excellent freehand circle. The way you made it kinda flat on the bottom really gives it that "artisan feel."

Comment: The linebreak in the logo makes me nervous

Comment: `world's leading companies and organisations`, uses only U.S companies...

Comment: off topic - This belongs on http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It's also the old logo @ChristianGollhardt

Comment: That organic non-gmo fhc is simply the best.  Please don't send me to Hell.

Comment: @cybermonkey these U.S companies are world's leading companies.

Comment: @Alex78191 In this context, 'world's leading companies' is invalid as it only includes U.S companies. `leading U.S companies` would be more appropiate.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Apparently we did use it a few years back for sales demos. I don't know if we still are, though, with Google Hangouts improving significantly since then.

So, the logo placement is legit. I don't think we can or should outright endorse any tool, though. I highly recommend you still do your due diligence and evaluate Screenleap for your needs.

Comment: So this is a case of screen before you leap?

Comment: @Machavity More votes on your comment than the answer. How often do you see this?

Comment: @JeruLuke easy to explain, we do love fun around here :)

Comment: @Stijn Wrong. voted to close as duplicate. (not srs)

Comment: @JeruLuke actually there was a meta feature request for that. it happens, sometimes https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279255/post-it-badge-for-totally-epic-comments

Comment: Even the logo-version they use is from that time.